# Use Google Play Billing inside Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just curious, can I use **Google Play Billing** functionality inside **Unity**? I see only Java & Kotlin examples, but maybe there is some plugin for Unity?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the prime31 In App Billing Plugin, which is used for several years now. https://prime31.com/docs#androidIAB

Unity provides also an IAP Module them self, which i have not used yet:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html

**Update September 2020:**
I now have used the Unity IAP module for a project on iOS and Google Play and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**[2020]** Google have released the ***Google Play billing plugin*** for Unity, which as per the Unity Package Manager description, "*provides all of the features available in the current Java and Kotlin versions.*" It is an extension of UnityIAP.

You can review their documentation, including installation instructions, [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/unity).

The documentation for the plugin doesn't include much in the way of examples like the Java and Kotlin documentation, but it is open-source, so you can review the files themselves to see what you are able to implement.

Comment: The OP asked is there any way to implement Google Play Billing functionality inside Unity itself?. Maybe you can add more information to make your answer more relevant to the question.

Comment: Edited the original answer to include some guidance for the plugin. The OP does not specify what they want to do, just that they know about the Java and Kotlin examples, so I can't help further on that, unfortunately. They directly ask about a plugin for Unity, so I feel that the explanation is sufficient as since this was asked there is now a plugin. Please let me know if there is anything else I can help with! (: